# Python read urls from file only gets last url

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to read a list of URLs and then output the html at a class. it works but only for the last url in the list and I can't seem to figure out why. I have  set timeouts etc but still it just returns and empty response except for the last url.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests
import time

with open('/Users/usrname/Desktop/links.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        html_doc  = requests.get( line, verify=False, timeout=2 )
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc.text, 'html.parser')
        #time.sleep(1.3) # seconds         
        print (soup.find_all("div", "location-content"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line in the file does not have a carriage return, while the others do and so are not valid URLs. You need to strip off the carriage returns with `rstrip()`

```
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
```